# Draw an ellipse or circle inside a UIImageView

Tags: ios, cgrect

I have an image created and I want to draw a ellipse or circle on it with parameters X coordinates, Y coordinates, Width and Height. I've search on google and found out that you can't draw inside a UI Image View.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tom.jpg"]];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

And can I add a filter effect like blur inside where I draw the ellipse or circle?

Comment: Try to check this [link][1] . It may be helpful to you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388061/ios-uibezierpath-and-cashapelayer-fillrule

Answer (score 1):

Refer this well explained article : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/

Creating a Circular Profile Image :

```
self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
self.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Adding Border :

```
self.profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
self.profileImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Creating Rounded Corner Image :

```
self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```